# apache change proxy request url rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have problem with proxy requests. I need to enable apache mod_proxy for my subdomains but i forgot to set Allow from mydomain.com, it was Allow from all...Yes, i created open proxy for all world... So, now when i set Deny from all, Allow from mydomain.com i am getting errors that some clients have been rejected because of server conf which is good, and in access.log i have get request for some urls with return code 403 which is also good. This is one of requests.

e.g.

```
GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1 403 462 "-"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0;)
```

My question is can i modify urls that is comming to me to some another url?

Can i change this url "google.com" to "mydomain.com"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting URLs can be done using mod_rewrite, which can be combined easily with mod_proxy.

There's ample documentation in [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)  which also contains links to the official Apache documentation.

Comment: Can you explain me little more, please? Where to put redirect rules? in htaccess of root? how to redirect all urls to mydomain.com?

Comment: All of that is answered in the link I included in my post.